# MVC 3 NopCommerce '$' character as part of the name of an url parameter

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, url-rewriting, routes, nopcommerce

I am working with NopCommerce by implementing the payment by credit card.I'm not using plugin but a simple redirect to the page of payment.Payment done then I get redirected to the page\view (http://localhost/Nop240/CreditCardPayment/Result) where I analyze the resultof the transaction reading the url parameters.

In the RouteProvider.cs class i have mapped the return url like this:

```
routes.MapLocalizedRoute("CreditCardPaymentResult",  "CreditCardPayment/Result/s/{session_id}/s/{codAut}/s/{alias}/s/{orario}/s/{data}/s/{mac}/s/{importo}/s/{cognome}/s/{nazionalita}/s/{pan}/s/{divisa}/s/{email}/s/{scadenza_pan}/s/{esito}/s/{codTrans}/s/{nome}/s/{messaggio}/s/{tipo_servizio}/s/{$BRAND}/", new { controller = "Checkout", action = "CreditCardPaymentResult" }, new[] { "Nop.Web.Controllers" });
```

In the controller i have writen this code

```
public ActionResult CreditCardPaymentResult(string session_id, string codAut, string alias, string orario, string data, string mac, string importo,                                                    string BRAND, string cognome, string nazionalita, string pan, string divisa, string email, string scadenza_pan,string esito, string codTrans, string nome, string messaggio, string tipo_servizio)
```

The return url is something like this

```
http://localhost/Nop240/CreditCardPayment/Result?session_id=w5pl05e3s2f1ki5bdg30xymy&codAut=TESTOK&alias=payment_testm_urlmac&orario=142525&data=20121008&mac=c62373ff789d451bcda0bb84d1d679114107aecd&importo=1&$BRAND=MasterCard&cognome=wwww&nazionalita=ITA&pan=525599XXXXXX9992&divisa=EUR&email=fabrizio%40xxx.net&scadenza_pan=201402&esito=OK&codTrans=0000000000000162&nome=wwww&messaggio=Message+OK&tipo_servizio=null
```

the problem is how intercept $BRAND url parameter.
Can help me please?

Answer (score 0):

have a look at url encoding here https://www.tutorialspoint.com/html/html_url_encoding.htm

you need to encode the dollar sign.